# Removing the gap between the datapoints

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[Graph: Number of Persons v DateTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RURG.png)

```
2004-12-23 15:25:01,8
2004-12-23 15:26:01,5
2004-12-23 15:27:01,5
2004-12-23 15:28:01,4
2004-12-23 15:29:01,4
2004-12-24 10:30:01,13
2004-12-24 10:31:01,12
2004-12-24 10:32:01,12
2004-12-24 10:33:01,13
2004-12-24 10:34:01,13
2004-12-24 10:35:01,13
```

As we can see there is no data between 2004-12-23 15:29:01 and 2004-12-24 10:30:01 but still the Google Chart shows me a gap and connects the two datapoints when using LineChart. Also I avoid making the dates string as then I would get no yaxis markings, because of the huge date-time.

I am new to using Google Charts, can this be avoided?

```
function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date-Time');
  data.addColumn('number', ‘Available);



  data.addRows(dataPoints);
  console.log(data);

    var options = {
    title: ‘Availability',
    legend: {position: 'bottom' },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time',
    /*
     viewWindow: {
        min: [7, 30, 0],
        max: [17, 30, 0]
      }*/
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Number of people available’
    }

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: try converting the dates to strings...

Comment: I did that but the problem that next comes is that I am unable to see the datetime. Any way to fix that?

Comment: will you please share the code that draws the chart?

Comment: Sure! I added the drawBasic function

Comment: @WhiteHat did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

if you use string values, rather than date values, no gap will be displayed...

```
  var dataPoints = [
    ['2004-12-23 15:25:01', 8],
    ['2004-12-23 15:26:01', 5],
    ['2004-12-23 15:27:01', 5],
    ...
```

also, here, needed to add more room at the bottom of the chart for the labels,
as well as increase the default height...

```
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 128
    },
    height: 400
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
  var dataPoints = [
    ['2004-12-23 15:25:01', 8],
    ['2004-12-23 15:26:01', 5],
    ['2004-12-23 15:27:01', 5],
    ['2004-12-23 15:28:01', 4],
    ['2004-12-23 15:29:01', 4],
    ['2004-12-24 10:30:01', 13],
    ['2004-12-24 10:31:01', 12],
    ['2004-12-24 10:32:01', 12],
    ['2004-12-24 10:33:01', 13],
    ['2004-12-24 10:34:01', 13],
    ['2004-12-24 10:35:01', 13]
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date-Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Available');
  data.addRows(dataPoints);

  var options = {
    title: 'Availability',
    legend: {position: 'bottom'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Number of people available'
    },
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 128
    },
    height: 400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```